# Como ler Yaml com Python?

Tags: python, yaml

Como eu faço para ler um arquivo ou código Yaml com Python?

É necessário instalar alguma coisa, ou dá pra fazer nativamente?

Exemplo:

```
fruits:
    - Apple
    - Orange
    - Strawberry
    - Mango
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem de instalar o modulo caso não o tenha:

```
sudo pip install pyyaml
```

Pode não ser preciso o `sudo`, dependendo do sistema.

E depois:

```
import yaml

with open("tests.yaml", 'r') as f:
    try:
        print(yaml.load(f))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Output para o que colocou:

> {'fruits': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Mango']}

[DOCS](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML)

Comment: +1. Testei aqui e funcionou certinho :p

Comment: :p.. Ainda bem @WallaceMaxters. Eu também não o tinha instalado, tive de instalar para testar

Comment: Gostei da library, pois ela parece seguir o mesmo padrão da do `json`.